# Include file relative path

Tags: org-mode

The Org Mode section on including files:

https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html

seems to be missing a detail. It appears that relative paths are allowed, I
assume they would be relative to the directory of the parent file.

That is to say if I have file `monday.org` including file `sunday.org`, and they
are in the same folder, then I could use this syntax:

```
#+INCLUDE: "sunday.org"
```

Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct: it's equivalent to the "./sunday.org" form that is mentioned in the manual.

Comment: @NickD if you have anything further to add, you should post as answer as I am inclined to upvote